# Angularjs ng-click is not working in dynamically generated list tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing angularjs application. I have generated lists with anchor tag. I am using ng-click to perform some task. The function written inside ng-click is not firing. I have below code.

```
var id = document.getElementById('ProfileDropdown');
id.innerHTML = $scope.ProfileDropdown = '  <div data-drop-down>' + ' <ul>' +
'<li ><a ng-click=gotouserprofile()>User Profile</a></li>' +
'</ul>'+'</div>';
```

Below is my ng-click function.

```
 $scope.gotouserprofile=function(){
    debugger;
    $state.go('Dashboard.Userprofile');
}
```

Whenever i click on user profile i do not get any error but i am not able to go to gotouserprofile function. I checked in browser. Below code generated.

```
<a ng-click="gotouserprofile()">User Profile</a>
```

May i know am i missing something in the above code? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You need to compile the HTML which you are preparing dynamically.

Comment: Thank you. Anil. May i know how can i compile the html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

need to compile the Dom again in order to call a scope function. use this

`$compile(id)($scope);`

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope,$compile){

var id = document.getElementById('ProfileDropdown');
id.innerHTML = '  <div data-drop-down>' + ' <ul>' +
'<li ><a ng-click=gotouserprofile()>User Profile</a></li>' +
'</ul>'+'</div>';

$compile(id)($scope);

$scope.gotouserprofile=function(){ 
    console.log("working")
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <div id="ProfileDropdown" ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great. Worked fine. Should i use directive for this or this will be enough?

Comment: it is better to create a directive if you do a scenario like this often

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that:

```
  var profileDropDown = '  <div data-drop-down>' + ' <ul>' +
'<li ><a ng-click=gotouserprofile()>User Profile</a></li>' +
'</ul>'+'</div>';
  var temp = $compile(profileDropDown)($scope);
  angular.element(document.getElementById('ProfileDropdown')).append(temp);
```